# Normalize Numpy Upper-triangular subarray

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy, normalization

I have an upper-triangular subarray of dimension 4. It is initialized as

```
N, Q = (99, 23)
bivariate = np.zeros((N,N,Q,Q))
```

and then populated by something like

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1,N):
        bivariate[i,j] = num
```

I want the upper-triangular elements to be normalized (Q,Q) matrices. I am currently doing this by just doing a

```
bivariate /= bivariate.sum(axis=3).sum(axis=2)[:,:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]
```

but I get Runtime Warnings due to the empty arrays of the lower-triangular portion being normalized. Is there a better way to do this other than the following?

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1,N):
        bivariate[i,j] /= bivariate[i,j].sum()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I've found that it's much easier to work on the upper triangular portion separately then insert it back in.

```
triu = np.tri_indices(n, 1)
upper_tri = bivariate[triu].reshape(-1, Q*Q)
upper_tri /= upper_tri.sum(axis=1)
bivariate[triu] = upper_tri.reshape(-1, Q, Q)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about getting `np.nan`, you could try to replace the null entries of your normalization factor by 1:

```
 norm_factor = bivariate.sum(axis=3).sum(axis=2)[:,:,None,None]
 bivariate /= np.where(norm, norm, 1)
```

At least you'll avoid the `for` loops...